# How to add a 'Click for more details' expandable field to AlertDialog in android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a AlertDialog that is shown when there is an error and it prints 'Error, could not be added/whatever", I also have the result of the exception that I'd like to parse but not shown to all users, only to those that want to click on 'details' and read the exception.

```
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogo1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            dialogo1.setTitle("Error");
            dialogo1.setMessage("Could not update movie: " + result);
            dialogo1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogo1, int id) {
                    activity.finish();
                }
            });
            dialogo1.show();
```

There is my code, pretty simple, right? I haven't been able to find this answer anyway and I'm starting to think it is just not possible

Comment: It's probably cleaner to use a DialogFragment with a custom view here. You can add your own button to change the visibility of a hidden field instead of using the system buttons.

Comment: google.com + dialog + custom view

Comment: and you also have an activity.finish() before closing the dialog..aren't you getting a Window LEak error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is a custom alert dialog.
so for that you will have to us a layout and define your dialog.Then initialize your listeners etc like it was a normal view that you are defining

dialog_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/header_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/error"
    andorid:text="Error Message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/moreDetailsButton"
    android:text="Click for more details"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/moreDetailsView"
    android:text="Click for more details"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone";
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" Ok "
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/moreDetailsButton"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in your class

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
TextView error=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.error);
Button errorButton=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.moreDetailsButton);
Button okButton=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);


//Do whatever you want with the rest of the dialog
// initialize all the onclick listeners a usual


errorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        TextView errorDetails=(TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.moreDetailsView);
        errorDetails.setText(detailedErrorMessage)  //add the details to this text view;
        errorDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }    
});

dialog.show();
```

Sorry if there are any syntactically errors if the ctrl+c,ctrl+v of this doesnt work.My IDE decided to misbehave today.

Follow [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) for details on a  custom alert dialog.

Comment: Layout is kinda wacky, I'll write my own version in an answer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error"
            android:text="Error Message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/moreDetailsView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moreDetailsView"
            android:text="No existen detalles para este tipo de error."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/moreDetailsButton"
            android:text="Click for more details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/moreDetailsView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/error"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
            android:layout_width="139dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/moreDetailsView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```